# How to move connecting path/lines in D3 to edges of shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and am having trouble working out how to move the connect lines in relation to the shapes they are connected to. I want to use large squares instead of circles.

Here is the original example with circles:

[image: circles]

I have changed circles to squares and this is how it looks:
[image]

I want it to look like this (Photoshop modified):
[image]

Here is the demo code I am modifying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tree Example</title>
    <style>
    .node {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];
// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");
function update(source) {
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);
  //nodeEnter.append("circle")
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      //.attr("r", 1e-6)

  //.attr("rx",0)
    //.attr("ry",0)
    //.attr("x",100)
    //.attr("y",100)

    .attr("width",100)
    .attr("height",100)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("fill","white")


      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  //nodeUpdate.select("rect")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();
  nodeExit.select("circle")
  //nodeExit.select("rect")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);
  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
      //var o = {x: (source.x0 + 100), y: (source.y0 + 100)};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });
  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();
  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding (width of box and half of box height) to starting position of links? Try this on when links are added to the canvas in enter method.

Answer (score 1):

Modify how the links are drawn to include the width and height of the rects:

```
// Transition links to their new position.
link.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("d", function(d){
    var s = {
      x: d.source.x + 50,
      y: d.source.y + 100
    }, t = {
      x: d.target.x + 50,
      y: d.target.y
    }
    return diagonal({source: s, target: t});        
  });
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tree Example</title>
    <style>
    .node {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];
// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");
function update(source) {
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);
  //nodeEnter.append("circle")
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      //.attr("r", 1e-6)

  //.attr("rx",0)
    //.attr("ry",0)
    //.attr("x",100)
    //.attr("y",100)

    .attr("width",100)
    .attr("height",100)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("fill","white")


      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  //nodeUpdate.select("rect")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();
  nodeExit.select("circle")
  //nodeExit.select("rect")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);
  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
      //var o = {x: (source.x0 + 100), y: (source.y0 + 100)};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });
  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d){
        var s = {
          x: d.source.x + 50,
          y: d.source.y + 100
        }, t = {
          x: d.target.x + 50,
          y: d.target.y
        }
        return diagonal({source: s, target: t});
        
      });
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();
  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```